# How to get started on using NorthScale Memcached Server

Tags: c#, .net, memcached, distributed-caching

I'm looking to use NorthScale's Memcached Server with Amazon EC2, I've launched a new instance using one of the AMIs on http://labs.northscale.com/memcached-ami/ but how do I go about configuring the bucket name, login credentials and the pool URL?

Do any of you guys know of any good introductory material to help me get started on working with NorthScale Memcached Servers?

Thanks,

p.s. I'm using EnyimMemcached as my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current AMI that is available on EC2 was built as a courtesy by NorthScale and actually only contains the community version of memcached.  Once up and running, you should be able to connect to it and use memcached on port 11211.

If you'd like the full NorthScale version, currently you'll have to setup an instance of a supported operating system and install the server directly.

We're working on providing a faster method to get up and running with NorthScale's server in Amazon...stay tuned.

Also, please feel free to communicate with NorthScale directly at forums.northscale.com or by sending an email.

Thanks!

Perry Krug